# How to execute a bash script line by line?

Tags: bash

```
#Example Script
wget http://file1.com
cd /dir
wget http://file2.com
wget http://file3.com
```

I want to execute the bash script line by line and test the **exit code** ($?) of each execution and determine whether to proceed or not:

It basically means I need to add the following script below every line in the original script:

```
if test $? -eq 0 
then
    echo "No error"
else
   echo "ERROR"
   exit
fi
```

and the original script becomes:

```
#Example Script
wget http://file1.com
if test $? -eq 0 
then
    echo "No error"
else
   echo "ERROR"
   exit
fi
cd /dir
if test $? -eq 0 
then
    echo "No error"
else
   echo "ERROR"
   exit
fi
wget http://file2.com
if test $? -eq 0 
then
    echo "No error"
else
   echo "ERROR"
   exit
fi
wget http://file3.com
if test $? -eq 0 
then
    echo "No error"
else
   echo "ERROR"
   exit
fi
```

But the script becomes bloated.

Is there a better method?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

Comment: This is not quite the same as the 'flagged duplicate' - But because of it I can't add my own (properly formatted) answer!

Comment: I am actually surprised no one came up with a 'trap DEBUG' solution.  You can use $? to get the wget exit value, $BASH_COMMAND to check that it is a wget,  and $BASH_LINENO to tell you which wget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use [`set -e` but it's not without it's own pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). Alternative one can bail out on errors:

```
command || exit 1
```

And an your `if`-statement can be written less verbose:

```
if command; then
```

The above is the same as:

```
command
if test "$?" -eq 0; then
```

Comment: Upvoted.  Though maybe emphasize even more that explicitly examining `$?` is almost never necessary, and that control statements such as `if` and `while` already do this, and that's their very purpose.

Answer (score 2):

`set -e` makes the script fail on non-zero exit status of any command. `set +e` removes the setting.

Comment: If I use this method, how can I know which line (in the original script) causes the error? I want to print that line.

Comment: @J.Joe , You can use `set -x` to achieve that. So `set -ex` should do.

Comment: @choroba Actually, I think a better method will be `2>&1 | tee -a log` so you can check the log anytime you want.

Comment: @J.Joe also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743026/how-to-display-last-command-that-failed-when-using-bash-set-e.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that.

For example can use [set](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) in order to automatically stop on "bad" rc; simply by putting

```
set -e
```

on top of your script. Alternatively, you could write a "check_rc" function; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195607/checking-bash-exit-status-of-several-commands-efficiently) for some starting points.

Or, you start with this:

```
check_error () {
  if [ $RET == 0 ]; then
    echo "DONE"
    echo ""
  else
    echo "ERROR"
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

To be used with:

```
echo "some example command"
RET=$? ; check_error
```

As said; many ways to do this.

Comment: If I use this method, how can I know which line (in the original script) causes the error? I want to print that line.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to use `set -e` to terminate the script as soon as any non-zero return code is observed. Alternatively you can write a function to deal with error traps and call it after every command, this will reduce the `if...else` part and you can `print` any message before exiting.

```
trap errorsRead ERR;
function errorsRead() {

   echo "Some none-zero return code observed..";
   exit 1;
}


    somecommand #command of your need
    errorsRead  # calling trap handling function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this contraption:

```
wget http://file1.com || exit 1
```

This will terminate the script with error code 1 if a command returns a non-zero (failed) result.