# How to do exception handling in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, system-administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error handling in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash)

I have one deployement script and i want to do exception handling in ubuntu shell script i.e. bash scripts. Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean by exception handling, but if you are looking for `try` and `catch` (or something similar) you are out of luck.  There is `set -e`, but I wouldn't say that was even close.  The nearest I can think of is the ERR signal trap (ERR is a fake signal)

For example;

```
trap 'echo [$LINENO] Error: $?' ERR
```

In this case we only display the line number and the return code, but you could place any code inside the quotes, including a function call.  The definition of a failure is a non-zero $?.  It is not executed for conditionals or arithmetic structures, and is not carried into functions.

The trap can be "switched off" with:

```
trap – ERR
```

See also the DEBUG fake signal.