# Is there a way to execute a command on exit (regardless of how the script exited)?

Tags: bash, exit

I have a script that writes out to temporary files to aid in its execution. At the end of my script I simply call `rm filename` to clean up the temp files I created. The problem is when the script ends due to error or is interrupted. In these cases, the `rm` statement is never reached and thus the files are never cleaned up. Is there a way I can specify some command to run on exit regardless of whether or not it was a successful exit?

Comment: Have a look here - might be what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use [**`trap`**](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) like so:

```
trap "rm -f filename" EXIT
```

---

A script could look like this:

```
#/bin/bash
trap "rm -f filename" EXIT   # remove file when script exits
touch filename               # create file
some-invalid-command         # trigger an error
```

Comment: Hmmm this doesn't seem to be working for me. The files still exist when the script exits

Comment: Try the example I posted, should work fine if you have permission to delete the file in question.

Comment: @imnotfred make sure to define this trap before the failing command

Answer (score 2):

Yes; you can write:

```
trap 'rm filename' EXIT
```

(See the description of `trap` in [§4.1 "Bourne Shell Builtins" of the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).)

Naturally there are extreme circumstances where the command will not be run — e.g., if someone suddenly unplugs the machine, or even just sends `SIGKILL` to the Bash instance running the script — but this is about as reliable as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

For interrupts, you can use `onintr` to specify a handler that removes the files, then exits.

Answer (score 0):

For interruptions: set up the script to trap signals like SIGHUP and SIGTERM.  This will help you with everything except for SIGKILL (which can't be caught).  Google "bash script trap signal"

For nonsuccessful exit: structure you code such that you call a function to rm filename (or just put the statement) before you exit the script