# Oracle Error Handling in Bash Script

Tags: oracle, bash, plsql

How can I error handling in SQLPlus , printing out customised messages when an error is encountered. I have put my code below.

My Code

```
#!/bin/bash

    echo "My Scripts run below"
    sqlplus -S UID1/UID2@DB1<< EOF
    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
    @/path/Script1
    @/path/Script2
    exit;
    EOF
   echo "My Scripts have run"
```

**Output**

```
My Scripts run below
SP2-0310: unable to open file "/path/Script1.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "/path/Script2.sql"
My Scripts have run
```

**Required Output**

```
My Scripts run below
**Below error in Script1**
SP2-0310: unable to open file "/path/Script1.sql"
**Below error in Script2**
SP2-0310: unable to open file "/path/Script2.sql"
My Scripts have run
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, SQLPlus return code is always 0 fr om my experience, so I advise you to do what I had to do in previous projects: redirect scripts output in a file, then parse it to find SPx-xxxx or ORA-xxxx expressions that indicate errors.

Answer (score 1):

`WHENEVER SQLERROR` detects an error in a SQL command or PL/SQL block. You should use `WHENEVER OSERROR` instead to catch operating system errors.

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
```

If in doubt which error code is returned, you could think about hardcoding a number:

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1
```

For clarity, I'd change the last `EXIT` to

```
EXIT SUCCESS
```

You won't be able to catch both errors for script1 and script2. After the first error, your SQL*Plus scripts exits and hands back control to bash.

About what to do with the exit code back in bash, see [Error handling in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash)