# Catch npm ERR! when running npm test from shell script

Tags: node.js, shell, npm

I have a shell script that recursively searches for package.json from a base directory and runs npm test like so.

```
find "$parent_dir" -name package.json -maxdepth 2 -execdir npm test \;
```

I want to intercept tests failure in the form of:

```
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

So I can have the shell script exit with an error status.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have similar quesiton ...

Comment: just found this question, which is similar to mine. Two years and no answers...

Comment: There is a related question that may solve this problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830326/ignoring-specific-errors-in-a-shell-script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring specific errors in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830326/ignoring-specific-errors-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 7):

Another 3 year late and was looking for solution in this too.

Finally found it and if these help others in future. I used shell script $? command, which returns the exit status of the last executed command. I.e. if a shell script fails it returns 1 while a 0 if it's success. NPM implements this return hence.

```
npm run test
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "SUCCESS"
else
  echo "FAIL"
fi
```

Comment: This did not worked for me. The script kept breaking at the line of the test. I finally solved with the answer from this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830326/ignoring-specific-errors-in-a-shell-script

Comment: Thanks, never is too late

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to execute something or stop execution of script if npm ERR! has been thrown?
This might help:

```
 if ./somecommand | grep -q 'npm ERR!'; then
      #what you want to do
      # exit executing the script
      return
    fi
```

Sorry what I am two years late, just joined the SO community.