# Consider a specific exit code not a failure and proceed

Tags: bash

I found questions about [ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231937/bash-ignoring-error-for-a-particular-command) [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830326/ignoring-specific-errors-in-a-shell-script) in shell scripts, but they ignore any error, not just a specific one.

My use case is that in some cases `my_command` returns an exit code -3 (253), but that is not a real error and any `&&`-chained commands should execute. In case of a different exit code != 0, it should stop.

So basically I'm looking for something like

```
my_command || $(($?==253 ? true : false) && next_command
```

and I've looked at the different options of [using ternary operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash), but none of them seem to apply to my case.

What can I do?

Comment: Use an if clause that check $?

Comment: is there a reason you want to keep your command as a one-liner ? If not, as Raman said, you're better off using a standard `if ... then ... else` block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems `cmd1 || $(($?==253 ? true : false) && cmd2`:

- A `)` is missing after `false`.
- You don't want `$(( ... ))` but `(( ... ))`. The former would *execute* the result of the expression (that is a number!) as a command. The latter just evaluates the expression and fails if the result is 0 and succeeds otherwise. Note that is the opposite of how exit codes work.
- `true` and `false` are not commands here, but variables. If an undefined variable is used inside `(( ... ))` its value is always 0. Therefore the command `((... ? true : false))` *always fails*.

Here is want you could have written instead:

```
cmd1 || (($?==253 ? 1 : 0)) && cmd2
```

Test:

```
prompt$ true || (($?==253 ? 1 : 0)) && echo ok
ok
prompt$ false  || (($?==253 ? 1 : 0)) && echo ok
prompt$ ( exit 253; )  || (($?==253 ? 1 : 0)) && echo ok
ok
```

However, the ternary operator isn't really needed here. The following would be equivalent:

```
cmd1 || (($?==253)) && cmd2
```

Despite that, an `if` would probably be better. If you don't want to use one inline, you can write a function for that:

```
# allow all exit codes given as the first argument
# multiple exit codes can be comma separated 
allow() {
   ok=",$1,"
   shift
   "$@"
   [[ "$ok" = *,$?,*  ]]
}
allow 0,253 cmd1 && cmd2
```

Or define a wrapper just for this one command

```
cmd1() {
    command cmd1 "$@" || (( $? == 253 ))
}
cmd1 && cmd2
```

Comment: Is (( ... )) a subshell? i mean, does ( .. ) and (( ... )) mean the same ?

Comment: @User123 Despite the small difference in looks there is huge a difference in meaning. `((...))` is an arithmetic context. In such a context things work *very* differently. It is a bit more like C than bash. `(...)` is a subshell.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have evaluates to a number (once you fix the missing closing parenthesis), which is not what you want; but you can refactor it slightly if you want to maintain the same sort of flow, at the expense of a subshell.

```sh
my_command || ( exit $(($?==253)) ) && next_command
```

Probably a less expensive and, all things counted, both more obvious and elegant solution is the trivial

```sh
my_command || [ $? == 253 ] && next_command
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, like this?

```
my_command; (($?==0|$?==253)) && next_command
```