# Ignoring specific exit code in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

*Note: Question does not duplicate [Ignoring specific errors in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830326) .*

---

Suppose it is needed to capture the leading  characters of a encoded representation  of a file.

In shell (tested in Bash), it is easy to use the following form:

```
encoded="$(< file base64 | head -c16)"
```

The statement functions desired, except under certain alterations to the environment.

Consider the following:

```
set -o errexit -o pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit
encoded="$(< file base64 | head -c16)"
```

The final line would cause termination of a script, because of the non-zero return status (141) given by `base64`, unhappy with closed pipe. The return status is propagated to the pipe and then to the invoking shell.

The undesired effect requires a workaround, such as follows:

```
set -o errexit -o pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit
encoded="$((< file base64 || :) | head -c16)"
```

The `:` has the same effect as would have the keyword `true`, to evaluate as a non-error.

However, this approach leads to a further unwanted effect.

The following shows a variation with a different error:

```
set -o errexit -o pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit
encoded="$((< /not/a/real/file base64 || :) | head -c16)"
echo $?
```

The printed code is zero. Now, a true error has been masked.

The most obvious solution, as follows, is rather verbose

```
set -o errexit -o pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit
encoded="$((< /not/a/real/file base64 || [ $? == 141 ]) | head -c16)"
echo $?
```

Is a more compact form available? Is any environment alteration available such that statements masks only the particular status code, without the explicit inline expression?

Comment: I doubt there's anything better. Distinguishing different exit codes is relatively rare, so there's no shortcut for it.

Comment: Your solution seems good; if you're using an unruly command a lot then you could define a function `mybase64() { base64 "$@" || [[ $? == 141 ]]; }`

Comment: I do not think you need round parenthesis, which will cause a process fork. Curly parenthesis should be enough.

Comment: @ceving: Might you suggest a working example for this idea? I have not discovered one.

Comment: Do you require a redirection as your input ? For what @ceing means, i guess it's : `encoded="$( { base64 $1 ; } | head -c16)"` with `$1` as the file.

Comment: @Zilog80: Giving the file as an argument may be cleaner than as  redirection, but the central issue, of capturing the exit code from the command, seems not affected by this choice.

Comment: Maybe you could write a version of cat or base64 that ignore SIGPIPE.

Answer (score 1):

First off, apparently, to actually provoke the 141 error the file needs to be fairly, large, e.g.

```
head -c 1000000 /dev/urandom > file
```

now, as you said, this script `sh.sh` will terminate before showing `encoded: ...`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit -o pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit

encoded="$(< file base64 | head -c16)"

echo "encoded: $encoded"
```

instead of checking for the error code, you could let `base64` continue to pipe the rest of its data to `/dev/null` by invoking `cat > /dev/null` after `head` is done:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit -o pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit

encoded="$(< file base64 | ( head -c16 ; cat > /dev/null ) )"

echo "encoded: $encoded"
```

now you will get `encoded: NvyX2Zx4nTDjtQO8` or whatever.

And this does not mask other errors like the file not existing:

```
$ ./sh.sh
./sh.sh: line 5: file: No such file or directory
```

However, it will be less efficient because the whole file will be read.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example program, you could also just change your approach. 16 base 64 characters represent 16 * 6 = 96 bits, so 96/8 = 12 bytes of data from the file are needed:

```sh
encoded="$(head -c12 file | base64)"
```

this will not cause SIGPIPE.

Comment: Yes, it may be true, but the question is about the general workings of the shell, not any specific commands.