# Bash script error checking

Tags: bash, error-handling

I'm somewhat of a Bash newbie (in terms of scripting) and want to know the preferred method of error checking. I'm writing a build script that goes through a number of commands and I want the script to stop if any of the commands exit with anything other than 0. Other than checking the response code after each command, is there a "universal" way of exiting the script if anything returns a non-0? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash It discusses various possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `set -e` at the beginning of your script.

It will stop the script from running after a command fails and the error code will be forwarded.

From bash documentation:

> ```
>   -e      Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist  of  a
>           single  simple command),  a subshell command enclosed in
>           parentheses, or one of the commands executed as part  of
>           a  command  list  enclosed  by braces (see SHELL GRAMMAR
>           above) exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does not
>           exit  if  the  command that fails is part of the command
>           list immediately following a  while  or  until  keyword,
>           part  of  the  test  following  the  if or elif reserved
>           words, part of any command executed in a && or  ││  list
>           except  the  command  following  the final && or ││, any
>           command in a pipeline but the last, or if the  command’s
>           return  value  is being inverted with !.  A trap on ERR,
>           if set, is executed before the shell exits.  This option
>           applies to the shell environment and each subshell envi-
>           ronment separately (see  COMMAND  EXECUTION  ENVIRONMENT
>           above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing
>           all the commands in the subshell.
> ```

Comment: The examples shown in this faq show when `set -e` doesn't exit **on purpose**. It's a good reference and these examples should be taken into consideration when writing bash. Anyhow, I strongly support the following statement: "Every script you write should include set -e at the top." check [this](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/) link regarding robust bash scripts for more info.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I wanted to make the OP and possible other readers aware of the fact that `set -e` can have undesired side effects.