# Shell script print line number when it errors out

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have been looking for a way to print the line number inside the shell script when it errors out.

I came across '-x' option, which prints the line when running the shell script, but this is not exactly what I want. Maybe I  could do $LINENO before every exit code? Is there a cleaner way to do it?

I just wanted the line number so I could open the shell script and directly go to the place where the interpreter realized the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using

```
PS4=':$LINENO+'
```

will add line number to the output of `set -x`.

---

If you *only* want to print that on errors, there's some risk of running into bugs in recent interpreters. However, you can try the following (first given in [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash)):

```
error() {
  local parent_lineno="$1"
  local message="$2"
  local code="${3:-1}"
  if [[ -n "$message" ]] ; then
    echo "Error on or near line ${parent_lineno}: ${message}; exiting with status ${code}"
  else
    echo "Error on or near line ${parent_lineno}; exiting with status ${code}"
  fi
  exit "${code}"
}
trap 'error ${LINENO}' ERR
```

Again, this *will not work* on some recent builds of bash, which don't always have `LINENO` set correctly inside traps.

---

Another approach (which will *only* work on recent shells; the below uses some bash 4.0 and 4.1 features) is to use `PS4` to emit the exit status and line number of each command to a dedicated file descriptor, and use `tail` to print only the last line given to that FD before the shell exits:

```
exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}> >(tail -n 1) # send set -x output to tail -n 1
PS4=':At line $LINENO; prior command exit status $?+'
set -x
```

Comment: It is risky if this shell script fails because of bash versions because it will be reused in different shells.
I think I will go with the first option of PS4=':$LINENO+'.  I don't really want the actual lines because it clutters the console, but if that's the safe way that works everywhere, so be it.

Comment: You can always check `$BASH_VERSION` and use different code depending on the result.

Comment: @user2441441, ...alternately, it's easy to make the last code work with older versions of bash *if you don't need stderr for anything else*.