# How to get the status of a subcommand in a bash script that is invoked with -e?

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script with -e option so it stops on any error, but want to allow a specific line to return an error code different to zero and use it in the logic:

```
#/bin/bash -e
do_something_and_return_errcode
if [ $? -eq 2 ]; then
    specific_stuff
fi
```

The script would normally end in `do_something_and_return_errcode`. I could avoid by doing

```
do_something_and_return_errcode || true
```

but this would make `$?` return `0` and I cannot use `$PIPESTATUS` because this is not a pipeline.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using `set -e` is [highly error-prone](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), and not universally agreed on as good practice.

That said, consider:

```
err=0
do_something_and_return_errcode || err=$?
```

Another option is simply to temporarily disable the flag:

```
set +e ## disable the effect of bash -e / set -e
do_something_and_return_errcode; err=$?
set -e ## ...and reenable that flag after
```

Comment: This is a better suggestion than what I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the solution suggested by Charles Duffy:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36727957/887539

Leaving this post for reference:

You could pipe it though, consider the following example:

```
% cat pipetst.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
false | true
printf "Pipe: %d, exit: %d\n" "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" "$?"
% ./pipetst.sh
Pipe: 1, exit: 0
```

This is a hack and shouldn't be used in production code, I would much rater remove the `set -e` and implement error handling where ever needed.

If you need the output to go to `stdout` you can just pipe to `cat`:

```
(echo hello; exit 1) | cat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIPESTATUS` to see return status from all of the pipeline commands.  See the Bash man page sections on "Pipelines" and the "PIPESTATUS" Shell Variable.  If the last command is always successful, then the script will not exit because of `set -e`.

```
> cat /tmp/emptyfile | grep "sometext" | echo "OK"; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
OK
cat: /tmp/emptyfile: No such file or directory
1 1 0
> touch /tmp/emptyfile
> cat /tmp/emptyfile | grep "sometext" | echo "OK"; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
OK
0 1 0
> echo "Find sometext here" > /tmp/emptyfile
> cat /tmp/emptyfile | grep "sometext" | echo "OK"; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
OK
0 141 0
```