# Bash: graceful function death on error

Tags: bash, function, shell, error-handling

I'm trying to find a way to emulate the behavior of `set -e` in a function, but only within the scope of that function.

Basically, I want a function where if any simple command would trigger `set -e` it returns 1 up one level. The goal is to isolate sets of risky jobs into functions so that I can gracefully handle them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want any failing command to return 1, you can achieve that by following each command with `|| return 1`.

For instance:

```
false || return 1  # This will always return 1
```

I am a big fan of never letting any command fail without explicit handling.  For my scripts, I am using an exception handling technique where I return errors in a way that is not return codes, and trap all errors (with bash traps).  Any command with a non-zero return code automatically means an improperly handled situation or bug, and I prefer my scripts to fail as soon as such a situation occurs.

Comment: I meant inside the function, just after entering.  But that does not work either.  This is not the way I do error checking, I should have checked first.  Removed that part of my response.

Comment: Sometimes, it's better to trap the trap!

Comment: What do you mean by "better to trap the trap"?

Comment: In my case, I was using `trap` cmd for a given signal or when something failed. I found that if you are graceful enough to call a decent function to show some meaninful info before actually exiting with `exit nn` and user is fast enough to click ^C at that moment, trap was calling it's graceful xyz() twice/more, I had to use a flag.

Comment: Indeed, you have to make sure you do not recurse into your error handling trap, either due to user intervention or a bug.  I have a framework I built (I literally use the same trap to catch all errors in all my scripts), so I do not mind the trap (actually the function it calls) to be quite a heavyweight.  The actual challenge is finding a good way to manage exceptions (i.e. controlled errors) separately from uncontrolled errors (non-zero return codes).  That's the really tricky bit : making it work, but without introducing to much additional code.

Answer (score 0):

Caution: I highly advise against using this technique.  If you run the function in a subshell environment, you almost get the behavior you desire.  Consider:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() (  # Use parens to get a sub-shell
        set -e  # Does not impact the main script
        echo This is executed
        false
        echo This should *not* be executed
)

foo  # Function call fails, returns 1
echo return: $?

# BUT: this is a good reason to avoid this technique
if foo; then  # Set -e is invalid in the function
        echo Foo returned 0!!
else
        echo fail
fi
false    # Demonstrates that set -e is not set for the script
echo ok
```

Comment: What would you recommend?  Error handling in bash scripts is something I have worked very hard on performing systematically (i.e. everywhere, and with some kind of a framework and not ad-hoc approach), and I am curious as to how other people do it ; I have not seen it discussed in depth anywhere.

Comment: `set -e` is the closest you can get to exception handling, but it's very primitive.  You can do a trap on return to handle clean up in the function and explicitly return on any failure (eg `cmd || return`), and that's probably the best you can get.

Comment: In terms of bash support, yes set -e and traps are pretty much what you have, but in terms of error handling support, you can build an exception handling mechanism that causes all unhandled non-zero return codes to cause the script to abort.  This is what I built, and I have never seen anybody else mention doing that that despite the huge advantages, in my view, in terms of long-term code reliability.

Comment: By the way, I know it sounds like what I am describing seems like set -e ; it really is not, but a few short lines do not allow any significant explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for "nested exceptions" somewhat like what Java gives.  For your requirement of scoping it, how about doing a `set -e` at the beginning of the function and making sure to run `set +e` before returning from it?

Another idea, which is not efficient or convenient, is to call your function in a subshell:

```
# some code

(set -e; my_function)
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  # the function didn't succeed...
fi

# more code
```

In any case, please be aware that `set -e` is **not** the greatest way to handle errors in a shell script.  There are way too many issues making it quite unreliable.  See these related posts:

- [What does set -e mean in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Error handling in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash)

The approach I take for large scripts that need to exist for a long time in a production environment is:

- create a library of functions to do all the standard stuff
- the library will have a wrapper around each standard action (say, `mv`, `cp`, `mkdir`, `ln`, `rm`, etc.) that would validate the arguments carefully and also handle exceptions
- upon exception, the wrapper exits with a clear error message
- the exit itself could be a library function, somewhat like this:

--

```
# library of common functions

trap '_error_handler' ERR
trap '_exit_handler'  EXIT
trap '_int_handler'   SIGINT

_error_handler() {
  # appropriate code
}
# other handlers go here...
#

exit_if_error() {
  error_code=${1:-0}
  error_message=${2:-"Uknown error"}

  [[ $error_code == 0 ]] && return 0  # it is all good

  # this can be enhanced to print out the "stack trace"
  >&2 printf "%s\n" $error_message

  # out of here
  my_exit $error_code
}

my_exit() {
  exit_code=${1:-0}
  _global_graceful_exit=1  # this can be checked by the "EXIT" trap handler
  exit $exit_code
}

# simple wrapper for cp
my_cp() {
  # add code to check arguments more effectively
  cp $1 $2
  exit_if_error $? "cp of '$1' to '$2' failed"
}

# main code

source /path/to/library.sh

...
my_cp file1 file2
# clutter-free code
```

This, along with effective use of `trap` to take action on `ERR` and `EXIT` events, would be a good way to write reliable shell scripts.

Comment: `set -e ` doesn't actually work at all for what I want. Even when set inside a function, the entire script aborts instantly. It's no different than setting it before I run that script.
http://pastebin.com/p84B5R8b

Comment: Just take a look at the subshell idea in my answer.  If you are writing something that needs to run reliably, `set -e` isn't recommended.

Comment: Your exit_if_error function is not what I was hoping for... but the more I look at it the more it makes sense. Without a real try/catch mechanism it's probably the best I can do.

Comment: I have used that idea a lot of times in production environments for a long time.  When the complexity increased, I switched to Perl for more reliability, but the basic approach didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Doing more research, I found a solution I rather like in Google's [Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml?showone=Checking_Return_Values#Checking_Return_Values). There are some seriously interesting suggestions here, but I think I'm going to go with this for readability:

```
if ! mv "${file_list}" "${dest_dir}/" ; then
  echo "Unable to move ${file_list} to ${dest_dir}" >&2
  exit "${E_BAD_MOVE}"
fi
```

Comment: There is no need for the echo.  `mv` already emits a nice error message.

Comment: Agreed. This is a simple example. A much more useful message would be what function it is in, why the failure is fatal, et cetera.