# How to tell if any command in bash script failed (non-zero exit status)

Tags: bash, sh, exit-code, exitstatus

I want to know whether any commands in a bash script exited with a non-zero status.

I want something similar to `set -e` functionality, except that I don't want it to exit when a command exits with a non-zero status.  I want it to run the whole script, and then I want to know that either:

a) all commands exited with exit status 0
-or-
b) one or more commands exited with a non-zero status

e.g., given the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

command1  # exits with status 1
command2  # exits with status 0
command3  # exits with status 0
```

I want all three commands to run.  After running the script, I want an indication that at least one of the commands exited with a non-zero status.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set a trap on ERR:

```
#!/bin/bash

err=0
trap 'err=1' ERR

command1
command2
command3
test $err = 0 # Return non-zero if any command failed
```

You might even throw in a little introspection to get data about where the error occurred:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3; do
        eval "command$i() { echo command$i; test $i != 2; }"
done

err=0
report() {
        err=1
        printf '%s' "error at line ${BASH_LINENO[0]}, in call to "
        sed -n ${BASH_LINENO[0]}p $0
} >&2
trap report ERR

command1
command2
command3
exit $err
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks @William_Pursell!

Answer (score 4):

You could try to do something with a trap for the `DEBUG` pseudosignal, such as

```
trap '(( $? && ++errcount ))' DEBUG
```

The `DEBUG` trap is executed

> before every simple command, `for` command, `case` command, `select` command, every arithmetic `for` command, and before the first command executes in a shell function

(quote from [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap)).

So if you add this trap and as the last command something to print the error count, you get the proper value:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap '(( $? && ++errcount ))' DEBUG

true
false
true

echo "Errors: $errcount"
```

returns `Errors: 1` and

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap '(( $? && ++errcount ))' DEBUG

true
false
true
false

echo "Errors: $errcount"
```

prints `Errors: 2`. Beware that that last statement is actually required to account for the second `false` because the trap is executed *before* the commands, so the exit status for the second `false` is only checked when the trap for the `echo` line is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a ready-made solution for your requirement.  I would write a function like this:

```
function run_cmd_with_check() {
  "$@"
  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && ((non_zero++))
}
```

Then, use the function to run all the commands that need tracking:

```
run_cmd_with_check command1
run_cmd_with_check command2
run_cmd_with_check command3
printf "$non_zero commands exited with non-zero exit code\n"
```

If required, the function can be enhanced to store all failed commands in an array which can be printed out at the end.

---

You may want to take a look at this post for more info: [Error handling in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash/185900#185900)

Comment: @GrishaLevit - you are right - I corrected the answer.  Looks like the quoting topic never stops being a little confusing...

Answer (score 1):

For each command you could do this:

```
if ! Command1 ; then an_error=1; fi
```

And repeat this for all commands

At the end an_error will be 1 if any of them failed.

If you want a count of failures set an_error to 0 at the beginning and do   $((an_error++)).  Instead of an_error=1

Answer (score 0):

You have the magic variable `$?` available in bash which tells the exit code of last command:

```
#!/bin/bash

command1  # exits with status 1
C1_output=$?   # will be 1
command2  # exits with status 0
C2_output=$?   # will be 0
command3  # exits with status 0
C3_output=$?   # will be 0
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  That doesn't directly answer my question.  You might be implying that I could modify the script to keep a running total of all exit statuses.  That would be a solution, but not a desirable one, as it requires adding 30 lines of code to a script with 30 commands in it, making it more difficult to read, and is prone to human-error by forgetting to add it to every command.  I suppose one could create a function and pass every command to the function.  Still rather cumbersome.  I'm hoping for something like a simple `set -e` type of solution.

Comment: @RobBednark This is probably the best you can do. Consider a command like `((x=0))`. That is technically a failed command, because the contained expression evaluates to 0. Anything automated would have to take things like that into account. The problem with `set -e` is that a failed command isn't necessarily an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your list of commands into an array and then loop over the commands. Any that return an error code your keep the results for later viewing.

```
declare -A results

commands=("your" "commands")

for cmd in "${commands[@]}"; do 
    out=$($cmd 2>&1)
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] || results[$cmd]="$out"
done
```

Then to see any non zero exit codes:

```
for cmd in "${!results[@]}"; do echo "$cmd = ${results[$cmd]}"; done
```

If the length of `results` is 0, there were no errors on your list of commands.

This requires Bash 4+ (for the associative array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DEBUG` trap like:

```
trap 'code+=$?' DEBUG
code=0

# run commands here normally

exit $code
```