# In a bash script: how to signal to the (human) user that an error triggered a premature exit?

Tags: bash, error-handling

Within a `bash` script, how can one signal to the (bash-script-calling human) user that a premature-exit error was triggered, with some sort of custom message?

I want to send an unmistakable failure message like

```
! ** !

Oops, something went wrong.
This script did NOT successfully finish.

! ** !
```

so that the user understands the script did not finish successfully. (Sometimes this point is not clear and the user mistakenly assumes the script finished successfully.)

Comment: More-detailed (possibly?), trap-based answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/185900/605356

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my comment, here is with expanding on ([Gilles Quenot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62504195/7939871)) how to preserve the error return code when exiting the script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'rc=$?; cat<<EOF >&2
! ** !

Oops, something went wrong.
This script did NOT successfully finish.

! ** !
EOF
    exit $rc' ERR

failme ()
{
  return $1
}

failme 10
```

Comment: Just a verbatim copy of my answer + a 'feature' not asked by OP

Comment: I (the OP) consider this a critical feature, even though it was certainly not explicitly requested. I consider passing through the return code for command failures to be essential for tiered script calling. Many thanks Léa.

Answer (score 3):

You should use this instead of `set -e`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'cat<<EOF >&2
! ** !

Oops, something went wrong.
This script did NOT successfully finish.

! ** !
EOF
    exit 1' ERR

[...] # code
```

Comment: Excellent. Works well. Thanks Gilles.

Comment: @GillesQuenot See my answer post