# how to throw error from nested shell script

Tags: macos, shell, unix

How can I throw error from nested shell script and make parent shell script to stop as well?

I have this shell script (a.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Testing if SDK build config is correct"

FILE="App/env/index.tsx"
CONST_TO_CHECK='[a-zA-Z_]*'
RED=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0`

if grep -Eq 'export\s*const\s*'${CONST_TO_CHECK}'\s*=\s*false' "$FILE"; then
  echo "${RED}Error: All values should be true for sdk build in env.ts file${reset}"
  exit 1
fi

echo "${green}Build config seems correct${reset}"
```

Which I run from `b.sh`. If `a.sh` throws error, I want to stop further execution in b.sh as well.

I am calling b.sh from a.sh.

Consider this to be my `b.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sh ./a.sh

rm -rf ios/ios-sdk/out/Frameworks
xcodebuild clean \
    -workspace ios/dyteClientMobile.xcworkspace \
    -scheme DyteSdk
```

### More code

Answer (score 2):

Add `-e` to your `#!`. (This is also called "errexit" in the options.)

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

In this mode, any command's failure (returning a non-0 value) will terminate the script. In order to ignore non-0 return values, add `|| true` to commands, for example:

```
./a.sh || true
```

This would execute `a.sh` and continue whether it succeeds or not. Avoid prefixing `sh` here. Just execute the script directly.

For more examples of error handling Bash, and more advanced tools like ERR  traps, see:

- [Error handling in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97101/how-to-catch-an-error-in-a-linux-bash-script
- https://linuxhint.com/bash_error_handling/
- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/bash-error-handling

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. So in my `b.sh` I replaced it with `#!/bin/bash -e` but it still continues to execute .

Comment: Copying your code and just adding `-e` in `b.sh` works fine for me. Any time it prints "Error:  All values should be true for sdk build in env.ts file" it also stops executing. Is this your actual code? Are you running `b.sh` as `./b.sh` or are you running it as `sh ./b.sh` (in which case you're disabling `-e`). If you want to run this by calling sh or bash directly, you can use `set -o errexit` in the script rather than `-e`. That sets the value directly without relying on the shbang execution.