# Capture GitLab pipeline error somehow for next job to use

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

```
# Stage to pull and push image
job1:
  stage: job1


  allow_failure: true

  script:

    # Pull image and save success
    - docker pull ${SOURCE_IMAGEURI}:${TAG}

    ...

    - docker tag ${SOURCE_IMAGEURI}:${TAG} ${TARGET_IMAGEURI}:${TAG} 
    
    # Job might fail here due to not enough permissions which is what I want to happen
    - docker push ${TARGET_IMAGEURI}:${TAG} 

    - echo "Error Message" > curldata.txt
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - curldata.txt
```

```
job2:
  stage: job2
  script:

    # Do something with the error that happened in job1

  when: always
  dependencies:
    - job1
```

So above is a part of a job that pulls and pushes an image. Sometimes the image will fail to push though as a safety step due to lack of permissions. How would I capture the error that happens so that I can send that artifacts to the next feedback job. This job will send the information to the user so he/she knows that they didnt have enough permissions.

Comment: If you capture the error as an environment variable you should be able to pass that to another job as a dotenv artifact: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am not sure what env var to capture and also it needs to be captured after the job fails which I am confused about because even if you allow failure, the job that fails will stop immediately and not capture the env var. Do you have any info on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `tee` the (stderr) output of the command to a file and artifact the file.

```yaml
script:
  # ...
  # show output of the command and store stderr to text file
  - docker push ${TARGET_IMAGEURI}:${TAG} 2> >(tee stderr.txt)
artifacts:
  paths:
    - stderr.txt
  when: always
```

If you need some logic to happen after the error, you can use and/or logic gates.

```
docker push ${TARGET_IMAGEURI}:${TAG} || echo "do this if it fails" > error.txt && exit 1
```

There's more to be said about robust [error handling in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash), but those are some basic ideas you can use.

Comment: Thank you, although I am not quite sure what the "2> >" part does, it solves my problem and I was able to capture that error message! Also, I have not used tee before so I am not sure the differences between that and a normal output without that.

Comment: The `2>` is a kind of output redirection. It says, basically, "send stderr somewhere"  `>(tee stderr.txt)` directs stderr into the [`tee` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html), which will read the input, and then write it to both the file `stderr.txt` AND to the screen (stdout). These may help: [bash: redirect stderr to file and stdout + stderr to screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333198/453397) and [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean) @JohnBaltimore

Comment: Thanks a bunch! One last question. So if I wanted logic if it fails, how would I get the stderr.txt with the error in it? "|| 2> >(tee stderr.txt) && do something" will have nothing in the txt file

Comment: The error is already written to the file before the the OR logic (`||`) kicks in. You need to have the `2> >(tee stderr.txt)` BEFORE the `||`. Also keep in mind if you do another redirection into the file again (like `echo "foo" > stderr.txt` ) it will truncate (delete) the contents of the file from the first command. Use `>>` to append. @JohnBaltimore Hope that helps. If you need more help with bash logic, consider opening a new question